# Magento product images new option

Tags: php, magento, admin

Hey guys, how do i add one more option to product image list? like Exclude & Remove checkboxes

Comment: You'll have to work with the Adminhtml files. What option are you planning to add?

Comment: I need to add one more checkbox option to product images list, let's say "Show on Flash" ... and in front-end developing i need to get all product images with this option set.

Answer (score 1):

@vrnet
You were almost there...
In addition, you would need to update:

1. /js/mage/adminhtml/products.js (ton of changes). Basically you would need to add code for JSON to handle your new field. I needed to add a second label on my end and ended up copyPasting label code and changing the variable names to match the code variable. Should be pretty straight forward.
2. (line 66) Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media class, you would need to add your new column so that it would be loaded back from the DB.

If you have any questions, drop me an email

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to code the same feature. Did you have an answer ?

The idea is to add a "Use as page" checkbox for each image in the image gallery. The goal being to make a JS carousel with all picture checked as "Use as page".

I have a few things done but I cannot update data in the database.

--> So my question is : how to update data in the database and retrieve it in the checkbox (0 or 1 depending on the checkbox) ?

Thanks all for your very precious help.

---

Here is what I've done (1.4.1.0) :

**1- Update table catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value**

Added a new field (which name is "page") :

- page      tinyint(4)          UNSIGNED    No      0

**2- Made the following changes to class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media**

*Line 49 :*

from

```
$localAttributes = array('label', 'position', 'disabled');
```

to

```
$localAttributes = array('label', 'position', 'disabled', 'page');
```

*Line 223 :*

from

```
$data['disabled'] = (int) $image['disabled'];
```

to

```
$data['disabled'] = (int) $image['disabled'];
$data['page'] = (int) $image['page'];
```

*Line 301*

from

```
$mediaGalleryData['images'][] = array(
    'file'     => $fileName,
    'position' => $position,
    'label'    => '',
    'disabled' => (int) $exclude
);
```

to

```
$mediaGalleryData['images'][] = array(
    'file'     => $fileName,
    'position' => $position,
    'label'    => '',
    'disabled' => (int) $exclude,
    'page' => (int) $exclude,
);
```

*Line 328*

from

```
$fieldsMap = array(
    'label'    => 'label',
    'position' => 'position',
    'disabled' => 'disabled',
    'exclude'  => 'disabled',
);
```

to

```
$fieldsMap = array(
    'label'    => 'label',
    'position' => 'position',
    'disabled' => 'disabled',
    'exclude'  => 'disabled',
    'page'  => 'disabled',
);
```

**3- Made the following changes to template adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml**

*Line 64*

from

```
    <th><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Exclude') ?></th>
```

to

```
    <th><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Exclude') ?></th>
    <th><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Is Page') ?></th>
```

*Line 77*

from

```
<td class="cell-disable a-center"><input type="checkbox" <?php if($_block->getElement()->getReadonly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?> onclick="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateImage('__file__')" /></td>
```

to

```
<td class="cell-disable a-center"><input type="checkbox" <?php if($_block->getElement()->getReadonly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?> onclick="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateImage('__file__')" /></td>
<td class="cell-page a-center"><input type="checkbox" <?php if($_block->getElement()->getReadonly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?> onclick="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateImage('__file__')" /></td>
```

*Line 105*

from

to

```
            <td class="cell-disable"><input type="hidden" />&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="cell-page last"><input type="hidden" />&nbsp;</td>
```